Tracking SMS Opens and Link Clicks in Marketing Cloud Custom Activity Integration
I'm integrating with a third-party SMS provider in Marketing Cloud via a custom activity. The custom activity will hardcode a message in the journey and split the audience with decisions. I'll be sending the SMS body to my custom activity built in Node.js, which will call the third-party API when the data is received. How can I track SMS opens and link clicks within this custom activity?

Firstly - you can’t track SMS opens. I like in emails, SMS does not provide you with the ability of having a tracking pixel, which you would normally use for registering opens. Also, having click tracking can be quite tricky, as this is normally done by directing the link in the email/SMS through a redirect URL which registers the click, before sending the recipient on to the actual destination URL. You can achieve something similar by using a link shortener, like bitly or similar, which can keep track on the number of clicks. It can although not keep track on who has clicked on your link.
Since you will be sending your entire SMS body to this external application, I would assume this would require this external application to automatically replace any URL in the payload with a bitly short-url.
Regardless, there is only little you can do in your custom activity. Most of the work should be done in the integration between this activity and your external application. It could be helpful if you shared what application it is, so we could provide more specific feedback.

I will be using NodeJS applicaiton as custom activity

@MuhammadSheheryarAfsar will nodeJS be delivering the actual text messages? I would assume you need AWS SNS or a similar application for handling the delivery itself.
